# Sales Order Confirmation Report - SalesConfirmDP

Tags: sql, axapta, business-intelligence, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I am modifying the SalesConfirmDP class and trying to add the CustVendExternalItem.ExternalItemTxt field into a new field I have created.
I have tried a couple of things but I do not think my syntax was correct i.e I declare the CustVendExternalItem table in the class declaration. But then when I try to insert CustVendExternalItem.ExternalItemTxt  into my new field, it does not populate, I guess there must be a method which I need to include?

If anyone has any suggestion it would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

```
private void setSalesConfirmDetailsTmp(NoYes _confirmTransOrTaxTrans)
{
DocuRefSearch                           docuRefSearch;
// Body
salesConfirmTmp.JournalRecId                = custConfirmJour.RecId;

if(_confirmTransOrTaxTrans == NoYes::Yes)
{
    if (printLineHeader)
    {
        salesConfirmTmp.LineHeader          = custConfirmTrans.LineHeader;
    }
    else
    {
        salesConfirmTmp.LineHeader          = '';
    }
    salesConfirmTmp.ItemId                  = this.itemId();
    salesConfirmTmp.Name                    = custConfirmTrans.Name;
    salesConfirmTmp.Qty                     = custConfirmTrans.Qty;
    salesConfirmTmp.SalesUnitTxt     =      custConfirmTrans.salesUnitTxt();
    salesConfirmTmp.SalesPrice              = custConfirmTrans.SalesPrice;
    salesConfirmTmp.DlvDate                 = custConfirmTrans.DlvDate;
    salesConfirmTmp.DiscPercent             = custConfirmTrans.DiscPercent;
    salesConfirmTmp.DiscAmount              = custConfirmTrans.DiscAmount;
    salesConfirmTmp.LineAmount              = custConfirmTrans.LineAmount;
    salesConfirmTmp.CurrencyCode            = custConfirmJour.CurrencyCode;
    salesConfirmTmp.PrintCode               = custConfirmTrans.TaxWriteCode;

    if (pdsCWEnabled)
    {
        salesConfirmTmp.PdsCWUnitId         = custConfirmTrans.pdsCWUnitId();
        salesConfirmTmp.PdsCWQty            = custConfirmTrans.PdsCWQty;
    }

    **salesConfirmTmp.ExternalItemText          = CustVendExternalItem.ExternalItemTxt;**

    if ((custFormletterDocument.DocuOnConfirm == DocuOnFormular::Line)
     || (custFormletterDocument.DocuOnConfirm == DocuOnFormular::All))
    {
        docuRefSearch = DocuRefSearch::newTypeIdAndRestriction(custConfirmTrans,
                                                               custFormletterDocument.DocuTypeConfirm,
                                                               DocuRestriction::External);
        salesConfirmTmp.Notes               = Docu::concatDocuRefNotes(docuRefSearch);
    }

    salesConfirmTmp.InventDimPrint          = this.printDimHistory();
```

Comment: Could you please post your code? Thanks.

Comment: Its a standard MS Dynamics AX class, the ** is the problem field

Comment: Can you add where you are populating CustVendExternalItem? Did you select that buffer in processReport()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, AX cannot guess which record you need, there is a helper class `CustVendExternalItemDescription` to deal with it:

```
boolean found;
str externalItemId;
...
[found, externalItemId, salesConfirmTmp.ExternalItemText] = CustVendExternalItemDescription::findExternalItemDescription(
                   ModuleCustVend::Cust,
                   custConfirmTrans.ItemId,
                   custConfirmTrans.inventDim(),
                   custConfirmJour.OrderAccount,
                   CustTable::find(custConfirmJour.OrderAccount).CustItemGroupId);
```

The `findExternalItemDescription` method returns more information than you need here, but you have to define variables to store it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the steps to solve this problem are fairly easy and i will try to give you a step by step approach how to solve this problem.

1) Are you initialising CustVendExternalItem properly? Make a record of the same and initialise it as Jan has shown above, then debug your code and see if the value is being initialised in your DP class.

2)If your value is being initialised correctly, but it is not showing up in the report design there can be multiple issues such as:

- Overlapping of text boxes.
- Insufficient space for the given field
- Some report parameter/property not being set correctly which causes
  your value not to show up on the report.

  Check these one by one and you should end up arriving towards a solution